# Software that can give me summaries of network speeds between different websites?

Tags: networking, network-monitor

I have 3 basic websites in 3 countries:

- EU
- US
- ZA

I want to be able to test the speed between these three servers. I.e.

1. How fast they are when connecting to each other?
2. How fast they are when connecting to a random website?

Is there something out there already designed for this?